# Meteor create 'your project name'

Tags: meteor

How does your computer know where to download a project when you type in "meteor create .... " from your terminal

Comment: I think you are getting it wrong. When you type that command, it creates a meteor application for you locally . It doesn't download anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you do *meteor create app* it creates a folder named app in the current directory.
So, if you are in */users/documents* and you do *meteor create app*, the app will be in */users/documents/app* .

See the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/
The books: http://meteortips.com/book/ and https://www.discovermeteor.com/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm reading the book your first meteor application and it's a good introduction.

Comment: but how does the command download the leaderboard package (the leaderboard.css , leaderboard.html and leaderboard.js files to my computer?

Comment: @waynelo I think it doesn't download anything, it creates the project like a boilerplate.  If you want to know more maybe you can study the source code:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor